# Git Shows head in the code and not my changes

Tags: git, github

I just pushed some code on Github and now I see the following in my code:

```
// HelloWorld Layer
@interface GameScene : CCLayer
{

    CCSprite *devil;
    CCParticleFire *fireball; 
    CollisionManager *collisionManager;
    Demon *demon; 
    Spaceship *spaceship;
    Scoreboard *scoreboard;
    Environment *env;
    int lives; 
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    CGSize windowSize; 
>>>>>>> 37190b1e49c75517ce26e1040aaaed12bd2a013c
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

This is a merge conflict which probably happened after you pulled some changes. You should have resolved the conflict before commiting by editing the area inside the markers and removing them. Feel free to read more about merging and conflict resolution in [the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Comment: I just want to push whatever I have on my local repo to the github repo!

Comment: Everything between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======` is from your local head, everything between `=======` and `>>>>>>> [SHA1]` is from the commit with the hash `SHA1`. Just remove the parts you dont want (including the markers) and thats it.

Comment: The source suggests that somebody else added `windowSize`. Now you have to decide whether you want to keep it or not, modify the file accordingly, commit, and push the changes once more.

Comment: You should decide whether you want the `CGSize windowSize;` and either keep it or delete it.  Then remove the conflict markers (`>>>>>>>>`, `====` and `<<<<<<<`).  Then you should `git add` that file, use `git commit` to record the new version and then push it as you would normally.

Comment: Sorry, crossed in the aether :)

Comment: I am the only one making the changes!! This is just weird

Comment: @azamsharp: Well, if you're the only one, you could still have done divergent things - perhaps committing, pushing, then amending your commit?